# How to make a workqueue consistent across replicas in kubernetes custom controllers?

Tags: go, kubernetes, controller, client-go

In the k8s.io/client-go package, we have a workqueue that is used for adding items to whenever informers detect changes to resources. I'm trying to figure out if there is a way, in the case we have multiple pods running the controllers, that the workqueue could be shared across the pods. Is there someway to achieve this other than using a PVC?

I do know that we can use a data volume and attach across pods by means of a persistent volume claims. Although, I would like to understand if there was some abstraction that k8s provides for this?